# MQTT.js and Webpack - "WS is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-4

I am trying to bundle one of our microservices which is using MQTT.js and I am struggling with really strange issue.

It is working fine without bundling, so `ws` is available in `node_modules`.

Stuff which I think matters:

**error:**

```
    TypeError: WS is not a constructor
        at WebSocketStream (dist/index.js:159329:16)
        at createWebSocket (dist/index.js:147450:10)
        at Object.buildBuilderBrowser (dist/index.js:147476:10)
        at MqttClient.wrapper [as streamBuilder] (dist/index.js:147937:36)
        at MqttClient._setupStream (dist/index.js:146471:22)
        at new MqttClient (dist/index.js:146452:8)
        at Function.connect (dist/index.js:147940:10)
```

**webpack config:**

```js
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const { NODE_ENV = 'production' } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  entry: { index: './src/index.ts' },
  mode: NODE_ENV,
  target: 'node',
  watch: NODE_ENV === 'development',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'ts-loader', options: { transpileOnly: true } }],
      },
      {
        test: /(\.md|\.map)$/,
        loader: 'null-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Function where it happens:

```js
createMqttClient(): MqttClient {
    return mqtt.connect(this.mqttOptions.url, { ...this.mqttOptions.options });
  }
```

The url is like: `ssl://url-to-our-mqtt`

Can anybody help please?

Comment: I think step one would be to check if WS is actually available in the generated bundle. If it's not, you know you are facing a build issue where the module is excluded from the build for some reason.

Comment: Try to run webpack without minification. Like in dev mode. If it works, than the problem is in webpack's minification. That's why it crash. Read more here https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#minification https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/#mode-production

Comment: @Grynets It runs without the minification. If it would be minified, I could not trace this issue.

Comment: Could you please show how and where you import `ws`?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into same issue.
The problem for me was that I used

```
 plugins: [
   new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^mqtt$/, "mqtt/dist/mqtt.js"),
 ],
```

in webpack.config.js order to fix the shebang error that comes with mqtt.js since it is a CLI tool.
Then instead I have used

```
  {
    test: [
      /node_modules[/\\]mqtt[/\\]mqtt.js/,
      /node_modules[/\\]mqtt[/\\]bin[/\\]sub.js/,
      /node_modules[/\\]mqtt[/\\]bin[/\\]pub.js/,
    ],
    loader: 'shebang-loader'
  },
```

And my problem was fixed. Do you also use mqtt/dist/mqtt.js instead of mqtt in your imports or if you do something similar to mine, the shebang-loader rule I have posted above might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same with Amazon aws-iot-device-sdk-js and Microsoft azure-iot-device-mqtt which both include mqtt.

The initial issue is the build error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/mqtt/mqtt.js Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
```

This error is caused by the package mqtt. Three files (mqtt.js, pub.js and sub.js) contain a shebang line

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

The solution using module replacement suggested some places

```
plugins: [
   new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^mqtt$/, "mqtt/dist/mqtt.js"),
 ],
```

unfortunately changes the build error with the run time error

```
TypeError: WS is not a constructor
```

As mentioned in other answers, webpack can be configured (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/)  to use the shebang loader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/shebang-loader)

TL;DR

Install shebang-loader

```
npm install shebang-loader --save
```

In webpack.config.js use the loader

```
module.exports = {
...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test:
                    [
                        /.*mqtt\.js$/,
                        /.*sub\.js$/,
                        /.*pub\.js$/
                    ],
                use: 'shebang-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```